# Cisco ip sla, making it more resilliant

Tags: networking, ip, cisco

I have recently set up this configuration: http://pastebin.com/9SWpqQnz

It is achieving the goal of having the route fail over to the backup ADSL line when the primary fibre ethernet line goes down.

It is, however, failing over for a short period of time every few hours or so.

I assume it is looking for a single missed ping?

Can anyone suggest how this might be tightened up a bit and made more reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
track 1 rtr 123 reachability
 delay up 60 down 20

ip sla 123
 icmp-echo 37.77.176.177 source-interface FastEthernet0/0
 timeout 2000
 frequency 10

ip sla schedule 123 life forever start-time now
```

Also it's probably worth pinging something a little further out on the internet, since your ISP could have issues that leaves your local loop up and running but the rest of their network is unable to forward traffic correctly.  On the other hand, if you continuously ping something random on the internet that you don't have authorization for you could get blocked or rate-limited, which will artificially fail over your default route.

Comment: Thanks! I've put this in and I'll let you know how testing goes.

Comment: Do you also recommend having a route specifically defined for the icmp-echo address? e.g. **ip route 37.77.176.177 255.255.255.255 FastEthernet0/0** where fa0/0 is the fibre ethernet interface

Comment: @phil-lavin You don't need routes for directly connected interfaces, the subnet mask indicates which IP's are on the local network.  Also since there is a source-interface specified for the SLA test the specific route is probably not necessary.  If you do decide to configure a specific route, specify both the interface and next-hop IP in the 'ip route' command.

Comment: I tested and confirmed that the source interface is where the icmp reply needs to be received.  So even if ping works from the router the sla will still be down if received on a different interface.  No route needed.